# How to find when xr session starts three.js webxr

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webxr

I want to toggle style property of my carousel catalogue when the ar session starts so I write this :

```
const session = renderer.xr.getSession();

session.addEventListener( 'start', function () {
                            slider.style.display = "block";

                        });
```

But it does'nt work , how to know when xr session starts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to know when xr session starts ?

It's best if you check the read-only property [renderer.xr.isPresenting](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/webxr/WebXRManager.isPresenting). When this property is `true`, you know a WebXR session is active.

Comment: Thanks a lot but can you suggest me an event listener rather than checking because I need a listener and want to check when it starts not active

Comment: there is an end listener which works but start does'nt

Comment: Try it with adding an event listener to the WebXR manager like so:  `renderer.xr.addEventListener( 'sessionstart', start );`.

Comment: first time it does'nt work and when I press back  button and press startar button again it works , what can be the issue

Comment: can you help me with this?

Comment: Sorry, I've verified the event listener by adding it to the `webxr_vr_cubes` example and using the WebXR API Emulator for Chrome. The event fires as expected.

Comment: My mistake was I attached the listener inside a condition which only worked when a frame is passed but first time there was no frame so I wrote it outside the condition and now it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

if anyone needs this still, I used this:

```js
import { VRButton } from 'three/addons/webxr/VRButton.js'
import { XRControllerModelFactory } from 'three/examples/jsm/webxr/XRControllerModelFactory.js';

export default class MakeVRExperience {

   constructor(){
      // other code

      this.setupVR()
   }

   setupVR() {

   // Other code

   const self = this

   function start() {
      console.log("start")
      self.scaleScene()
    }

    this.renderer.xr.addEventListener('sessionstart', start)
    }

   scaleScene() {
        // Do smthg
       }
}
```